# Show/Hide Div using jQuery with select box

Tags: jquery, html, select, hide, show

I am new to jQuery and I am trying to make a form that will show and hide options depending on what the user selects from a drop down select box. I have searched on here but have not found a solution that works for me yet. I found a tutorial that essentially did what I wanted, however it only seems to apply to select boxes. Any help is appreciated.

This is the HTML code I am working with.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#emeorg").change(function(){
    switch($(this).val()){
        case "add":
            $("#test1").slideDown("slow");
            $("#changebox select:not(#emeorg, #test1)").slideUp("slow");
        break;
        case "edit":
            $("#test2").slideDown("slow");
            $("#changebox select:not(#emeorg, #edithidden)").slideUp("slow");
        break;
        case "remove":
            $("#test3").slideDown("slow");
            $("#changebox select:not(#emeorg, #removehidden)").slideUp("slow");
        break;
    }
});
});
```

This is the HTML code I am using.

```
<div id="changebox">
<fieldset>
<legend><strong>Emergency Organization Information</strong></legend>
<div id="prompt">Select Action:</div><div id="answer"><select id="emeorg" name="emeorg">
        <option value="add">Add New Org</option>
        <option value="edit">Edit Existing Org</option>
        <option value="remove">Remove Existing Org</option>
        </select></div>
<div id="edithidden" style="display:none;">
<div id="prompt">Section to Edit:</div>
<div id="answer">
<select id="test2">
    <option>Section to Edit</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
<div id="removehidden">
<div id="prompt">Section to Remove</div>
<div id="answer">
<select id="test3">
    <option>Section to Remove</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
<div id="prompt">Organization Name:</div><div id="answer"><input type="text" name="companyname" id="companyname" /></div>
<div id="prompt">Organization Phone Number:</div><div id="answer"><input type="text" name="companyname" id="companyname" /></div>
<div id="prompt">Orginization Location:</div><div id="answer"><input type="text" name="companyname" id="companyname" /></div>
<div id="test3"><div id="prompt">Orginization Location Remove:</div><div id="answer"><input type="text" name="companyname" id="companyname" /></div></div>
<div id="prompt"><input type="submit" id="maininfoupdate" value="Update Information" /></div>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

I just cant figure out why the divs will not show. to test the only one I have inline styled is the edithidden to be display:none;. There is no effect on that one, the removehidden however shows just the select box for a second then it slides back up.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

***EDIT***

Revised jQuery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#emeorg").change(function(){
    switch($(this).val()){
        case "add":
            $("#changebox select:not(#emeorg, #test1)").slideUp("slow");
        break;
        case "edit":
            $("#edithidden").slideDown("slow");
            $("#changebox select:not(#emeorg, #edithidden)").slideUp("slow");
        break;
        case "remove":
            $("#removehidden").slideDown("slow");
            $("#changebox select:not(#emeorg, #removehidden)").slideUp("slow");
        break;
    }
});
});
```

Revised HTML code:

```
<div id="changebox">
<fieldset>
<legend><strong>Emergency Organization Information</strong></legend>
<div id="prompt">Select Action:</div><div id="answer"><select id="emeorg" name="emeorg">
        <option value="add">Add New Org</option>
        <option value="edit">Edit Existing Org</option>
        <option value="remove">Remove Existing Org</option>
        </select></div>
<div id="edithidden" style="display:none;">
<div id="prompt">Section to Edit:</div>
<div id="answer">
<select id="editcontent">
    <option>Section to Edit</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
<div id="removehidden" style="display:none;">
<div id="prompt">Section to Remove</div>
<div id="answer">
<select id="removecontent">
    <option>Section to Remove</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
<div id="prompt">Organization Name:</div><div id="answer"><input type="text" name="companyname" id="companyname" /></div>
<div id="prompt">Organization Phone Number:</div><div id="answer"><input type="text" name="companyname" id="companyname" /></div>
<div id="prompt">Orginization Location:</div><div id="answer"><input type="text" name="companyname" id="companyname" /></div>
<div id="prompt"><input type="submit" id="maininfoupdate" value="Update Information" /></div>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

Now when I select edit the section for edithidden slides down, but no select box appears. When I change it back to Add it does not hide the garbage that edit slid down. I guess some progress is being made at least. Thanks again for all your help thus far.

Comment: I see two elements with `id="test3"` which isn't really illegal but it will prevent elements from being selectable via jQuery selector. Ooooh now I see you have a big issue with that. Please make sure that each id appears only once per page.

Comment: I just noticed the id="test2" and id="test3" are still in there, those have been changed to reflect "#edithidden" and "removehidden" respectively

Comment: Please show your most recent markup ... removing all the duplicate id attributes

Comment: <div id="edithidden" style="display:none;">
    <div id="prompt">Section to Edit:</div>
    <div id="answer">
    <select id="editcontent">
     <option>Section to Edit</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="removehidden">
    <div id="prompt">Section to Remove</div>
    <div id="answer">
 <select id="removecontent">
     <option>Section to Remove</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    </div>

Comment: @user1879572 is this something close to what you need?  I still don't know where test1 is http://jsfiddle.net/jU5wA/

Comment: @wirey Thanks! thats exactly what I was looking to do. It works great on the jsfiddle site, not on my app but I'm sure I can tweak it to work properly. Thanks so much for your help and everyone else too! BTW test1 was removed, didnt see that it was not yet removed from the pasted code though.

Comment: @wirey if I had multiple instances of this on the same page would I just stack the jQuery code and change the dive names to be closed? I have tried that and the inital code still works but the next section nothing happens. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/jU5wA/8/)

Comment: can you put your html inside a fiddle? that way I can see what you need

Comment: just added the link to it a second ago. [http://jsfiddle.net/jU5wA/8/](http://jsfiddle.net/jU5wA/8/)

Comment: @wirey just an FYI, I tweaked the code a little more. All the sections I am making should act like this [http://jsfiddle.net/jU5wA/17/](http://jsfiddle.net/jU5wA/17/) i just cant figure out how to stack the jQuery to make it work.

Comment: Ah.. I think the only issue was you had `<option id=` instead of `<option value=` http://jsfiddle.net/re8Rb/

Answer (score 0):

The `.slideDown()` method animates the height of the matched elements. This causes lower parts of the page to slide down, making way for the revealed items.

I don't see anything to tell us how you're hiding the elements in the first place. simply using `.show()` and `.hide()` should work.

Comment: I have revised the code to get rid of the rest of the page for testing here. I used the slide just for animation purposes here and have added and inline    style="display:none;" to the divs I dont want showing at first. The idea is when the select box changes the other options slideup or are hidden. for some reason however the entire div will not display, only the select box